# How to change type of a cell based on its value in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have an excel 2013 file including the data:

```
User  LastLogin
A     03/15/2020
B     user's machine not found
C     03/09/2020
D     03/25/2020
E     user's machine not found
```

The type of the `LastLogin` column is "Text".

I need to define a condition or develop a VB script to change the type of the cell based on its value. When it is a date, the format should be "Date", otherwise should be "Text".

I've checked examples online but only could find some that change the UI of the cell (highlighting etc.). How to change the type of the cell based on its value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just format the whole column as Date.

Comment: Since dates are stored as numbers, perhaps you could use [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.office.com/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) to check if it's text or numeric, and use that as part of a [formula in conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/article/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f#ocpVideo0) to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.  (But as stated, there's no reason you can't put text in a cell formatted as date. What do you expect the cell formatting to change?)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the format of a cell is generally recognized and set as soon as a value is entered, unless the format of the cell is specified as text. Therefore, after converting the text format to another format in the cell format, entering the value again automatically sets it. After setting the date format, if the text value comes, it will not appear in the date format.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, rngDB As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    Set rngDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    vDB = rngDB
    With Ws
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]